# How to extract a callback?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code that works just fine, but I'm trying to minimize it so I don't have to repeat myself by calling the format function twice.

This is what my code looks like:

```
if(date.indexOf('/') !== -1){
    return format(new Date(date), formatType);
}
else {
   return format(toDate(date), formatType);
}
```

as you can see I'm using return format twice (inside my if and else statements) and I'm trying to avoid the rule DRY.

Now This is what I have but doesn't work.

```
let fn = (fn) => format(fn(date), formatType);
return date.indexOf('/') !== -1 ? fn(new Date) : fn(toDate);
```

Can anyone point me in the same direction? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the conditional operator inside the call to `format`, alternating the first argument:

```
return format(
  date.includes('/') ? new Date(date) : toDate(date),
  formatType
);
```